# Does SOA need a network?

Tags: soa

Do the services in a service oriented architecture need to communicate across a network interface?  OR can the services sit on the same computer without even touching `localhost`?  If so, are there any examples of this?

Comment: You're still using network (local) when using localhost

Comment: I said "without localhost" NOT "with localhost".  Your statement and my post agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can - service orientation is an architectural style which you can implement in many ways. An example for in memory implementation is [OSGI](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage) standard see [this presentation for example](http://www.slideshare.net/bosschaert/benefits-of-osgi-in-practise)